# Php foreach loop key print a particular value

Tags: php, foreach, key-value

i'm trying to get individual values from an php foreach loop.

My code is

```
$foo = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'ball', 'c' => 'coke');

foreach($foo as $key => $item) {
  // Need to display only one array value any key like below,
  // First entry Key : a
  // First entry value: apple
}
```

Help me to do this ?

Comment: What do you need help with? You are already there. For a complete example in the manual Google `php foreach`

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your question, but in your loop, echo $key; echo $item;

Comment: @eddie jaoude,.. It'll return all array values. I need to print only certain value.

Comment: @Vin_fugen what is the condition? Only the 1st item in the array? See my answer below

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16558080/1338292) has three parts ... so what was the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$foo = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'ball', 'c' => 'coke');

foreach($foo as $key => $item) {
  echo $key;
  echo $item;
}
```

will output

```
a apple b ball c coke
```

or if you want the first item only, use

```
echo $foo['a'];
```

will output

```
apple
```

or to get the first array item without knowing the key

```
$keys = array_keys($foo);
$values = array_values($foo);
echo $keys[0];
echo $values[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you're only interested in the first key and value.

First value:

```php
echo current($foo);
```

First key:

```php
echo key($foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you only have to do

```
foreach($foo as $key => $item) {   
    echo $key;
    echo $item;
}
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` with `in_array`. This will only print `a` and `apple`

```
foreach($foo as $key => $item) {
   if(!in_array($key,array('b','c'))) {
       echo $key;
       echo $item;
   }
}
```

## Output

```
a
apple
```

## Codepad

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $value)
  if($value['email']==$value) {
    $selected='selected';
  } else {
    $selected='';
  }
```